# Passing and assigning value for a static unsigned char in class

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, pass-by-reference, destructor

I have this code, I am not able to copy the unsigned char passed to the class constructor to unsinged char variable in the class.

Main File

```
static unsigned char ic_opacity_black_24dp_bits[] = {
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00,
};
String cc="hello"
ICON a(cc,ic_opacity_black_24dp_bits);
```

Icon.h

```
#ifndef ICON_H
#define ICON_H
class ICON
{
  private:
    String title;
    static unsigned char _update_icon_bits[];

  public:
    ICON(String,unsigned char*,U8G2 u8);
    ~ICON();
};

#endif
```

ICON.CPP

```
#include"ICON.h"
#define DHEIGHT 128
#define DWIDTH 64

ICON::ICON(String _title,unsigned char *ic, U8G2 u8)
{
//initializing values 
 title=_title;
_update_icon_bits=ic;


}

ICON::~ICON() ///default distructor
{
}
```

I am not getting the value of passsed char array in my class variable.What should be the way to pass char array to assing value to a variable in the class?

Comment: Can't you use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` for an easy life? Otherwise you'll have to pass the size in to the ICON constructor, and use `::memcpy` or similar.

Comment: I am new to C syntax can you share an example please.

Comment: What is the exact issue you are getting? does it compile without warnings with `-Wall -Werror`?

Comment: **C++ is not C is not C++!** If you think this is C code, you are either in the wrong course or reading the wrong book. And we are not a tutoring/"gimme teh codez" site

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value to an array type. You can:

- make it a pointer `static unsigned char* _update_icon_bits;`
- keep it as an array but copy content to this array using a for loop or something
- use `std::vector` instead (preferred)